# Sending mail from PHP with exim4

Tags: php, email, debian, exim

A web server I manage is having problems sending mail from PHP. This server uses exim4 for MTA, and it is configured correctly.

I can send emails from PHP's CLI, but not from the web. i.e. if I do "php mailtest.php" on the command line, the email gets sent correctly, but if I browse to server.com/mailtest.php, mail() returns false and the email never gets sent. Nothing appears in the exim mainlog.

Any advice, or things I should look for ?

Thanks!

Comment: What distro? Are you running in an SELinux-protected configuration?

Comment: @jgoldschrafe Debian 5.0.6 and no.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It seems like permission issue. Have you fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've got different versions of php.ini located under /etc/php5/

```
debian:/etc/php5# find . | grep php.ini
./cli/php.ini
./apache2/php.ini
```

Check the [mail function] directive

Comment: I did, they're the same in both files. I actually copied one to the other (and the other way around) and got the exact same results

Comment: Do a phpinfo() and add the php server information "sendmail" to your question. Exim will normally replace the sendmail binary with the send compartible exim binary.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your PHP configuration to send emails through `exim`.

If you use `Apache2` as a webserver:

```
; /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mail.ini 
[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/exim4 -t
mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = syslog
```

If you use `nginx`+`FPM`:

```
; /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/mail.ini
[mail function]
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/exim4 -t
mail.add_x_header = On
mail.log = syslog
```

Then restart your services:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```